# docker compose exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have dockerized rails application. My environment is Windows 10 and i have already instlall docker. I am trying to build the project and it is fine. But when i am trying to

```rb
docker-compose run api rails db:create
```

it caused error like this

```rb
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

i already try to change from CLRF to EOL by using vscode.
but the error still same.

i already use dos2unix but the problem still same

this is my dockerfile

```rb
FROM ruby:2.6.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs libmagickwand-dev
RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick --fix-missing
RUN mkdir /nectico
WORKDIR /nectico
COPY Gemfile /nectico/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /nectico/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem update --system && gem install bundler -v 1.17.3 && bundle install
COPY . /nectico

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

how to solve this?
thanks

Comment: I believe you are mixing concepts, one thing is the Dockerfile and the other one is the docker-compose.yaml file. They are completely different. Docker-compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)

Comment: What's in the `entrypoint.sh` file?  Does `docker-compose up` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe someone will need it.

1. stop and remove the container and i delete the project
2. type git config --global core.eol lf
3. type git config --global core.autocrlf input
4. clone the project again
5. build the image again

Answer (score 0):

You copy sh file to `/usr/bin` but set workdir `/nectico`. So it try to find in that path. Just use `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh"]` and use docker run commands.